# match specific columns to another file

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I was about to find column 1 and 3 from a fileA to col 2 and 4 of fileB.

file1

```
  111111,22222,555555
  xxxxxx,555555,yyyyy
```

file2

```
  xxxxxx,111111,oooooo,555555
  yyyyyy,222222,111111,555555
```

output

```
  111111,22222,555555 | xxxxxx,111111,oooooo,555555
```

So far, this code below only matches column 1 (fileA) from column 2(fileB).

```
 awk -F, '{print $1}' fileA | grep "$(awk -F, '{print $2}' fileB)"
```

Comment: what if there are more matching lines? how will the output like then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single awk script to process the files. E.g:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3]=$0;next}($2,$4)in a{print a[$2,$4]" | "$0}' fileA fileB
111111,22222,555555 | xxxxxx,111111,oooooo,555555
```